# Problema con capturar la hora con date("ymd") PHP

Tags: php, date, time

Tengo esa variable para tomar la fecha actual

> $fecha_actual = date("ymd");

tengo un problema no se la hora exacta pero posterior a las tipo 6pm a 8pm toma el dato como la fecha actual+1

alguna solucion para ello? si hago:

> $fecha_actualnew = date("ymd",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 days"));

con eso le restaria 1 dia a la fecha que toma pero el problema es si no hay una solucion mejor para la toma de fecha o este problema es comun en php ?

Comment: Esto dependera de la configuracion de tu servidor, puedes hacer un echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); para ver que imprime

Comment: Note que me manda 5 horas de retraso, estoy usando XAMP al revisar el php.ini me contre que el date.timezone= esta vacio 
le coloque la zona 
>;date.timezone=America/Caracas
y aun tiene el problema envio lo que tiene el php.ini del XAMP
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone = America/Caracas
; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667
; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333
; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333
; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333

Comment: Si pero tambien debe haber un php.ini de apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabajar con fechas en PHP te recomiendo que uses la clase [**`DateTime`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php).

Para crear la fecha actual es tan fácil como esto:

```
$fechaActual=new DateTime();
```

Estarías creando un verdadero objeto que luego puedes configurar a tu gusto usando su enorme cantidad de métodos y clases relacionadas.

Lo puedes también presentar en pantalla con un determinado formato.

Puedes verificar también en qué `TimeZone` el sistema te está creando el objeto y cambiar la zona. Es muy útil cuando por ejemplo no quieres alterar la `TimeZone` del sistema, pero sí de ese objeto en concreto.

Veamos un ejemplo donde creamos un objeto `DateTime`. Usaremos `var_dump`  para ver su estructura y veremos un ejemplo de imprimir una fecha / hora con un formato determinado:

```
$fechaActual=new DateTime();
/*Sólo para ver el objeto*/
var_dump($fechaActual);
/*Un ejemplo de salida de fecha con formato*/ 
echo "Fecha/Hora: ".$fechaActual->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
-------var_dump------------------------------

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-11-05 03:08:52.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}

-------fecha formateada---------------------

Fecha/Hora: 2018-11-05 03:08:52+01:00
```

Ahora cambiamos el `TimeZone` usando el método `setTimezone`:

```
$fechaActual->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Caracas'));
var_dump($fechaActual);   
echo "Fecha/Hora: ".$fechaActual->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
-------var_dump------------------------------

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-11-04 22:08:52.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(15) "America/Caracas"
}

-------fecha formateada---------------------

Fecha/Hora: 2018-11-04 22:08:52-04:00
```